# How to generate debconf for specific packages?

Tags: debian, vagrant, debconf

I try to clone a Debian10 computer in a VM automatically via [vagrant](/questions/tagged/vagrant).

I start from scratch with [packer](/questions/tagged/packer) then reinstall all the packages and configurations.

So, I tried from hardware computer:

```
dpkg --get-selections > dpkg
debconf-get-selections > debconf
```

then import them from the VM :

```
debconf-set-selections < debconf
apt-get -y install dselect
dselect update
dpkg --force-confold --set-selections < dpkg
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dselect-upgrade
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" -f install
```

All is working as expected, but, for `msmtp` and `phpldadmin`, I get prompted to choose the old config in a dialog box in the pseudo-terminal via `ucf`.

How can I feed `debconf` (or other trick) to auto reply to these two dialogs automatically?

I tried to update `debconf` since manually choosing the dialog, but didn't work.

The `pstree`:

```
  │                       └─dpkg,18446 --force-confold -i phpldapadmin_1.2.2-6.1~bpo9+1_all.deb
  │                           └─frontend,18456 -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/phpldapadmin.postinst configure 
  │                               ├─phpldapadmin.po,18470 -e /var/lib/dpkg/info/phpldapadmin.postinst configure 
  │                               │   └─ucf,18483 /usr/bin/ucf --debconf-ok /tmp/tmp.eP3bVeYBPp /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php
  │                               └─whiptail,18522 --backtitle Package configuration --title Configuring phpldapadmin --output-fd 11 --nocancel --default-item ...
```

[image]

From `man dpkg`:

> confold: If a conffile has been modified and the version in the package did change, always keep the old version without  prompting,  unless  the  --force-confdef  is  also specified, in which case the default action is preferred.

But I get prompted, even with this switch.

`msmtp` debconf:

```
$ grep msmtp debconf 
# Action souhaitée pour le fichier de configuration modifié msmtprc :
msmtp   msmtp/auto_from boolean true
msmtp   msmtp/tls   boolean on on on /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
msmtp   msmtp/host  string  smtp.foobarmail.com
msmtp   msmtp/maildomain    string  
msmtp   msmtp/port  string  587
msmtp   msmtp/sysconfig boolean true
```

`phpldapadmin` debconf:

```
$ grep phpldapadmin ../../files/debconf.db 
phpldapadmin    phpldapadmin/restart-webserver  boolean true
phpldapadmin    phpldapadmin/ldap-authtype  select  session
phpldapadmin    phpldapadmin/ldap-server    string  127.0.0.1
phpldapadmin    phpldapadmin/ldap-basedn    string  xxxx
phpldapadmin    phpldapadmin/ldap-bindpw    string  secret
phpldapadmin    phpldapadmin/ldap-tls   boolean false
phpldapadmin    phpldapadmin/reconfigure-webserver  multiselect apache2
phpldapadmin    phpldapadmin/ldap-binddn    string xxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved like this:

```
export LANG=C
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive # very important
debconf-set-selections < debconf
apt-get -y install dselect
dselect update
dpkg --force-confold --set-selections < /root/pkgs
apt-get -y update
yes '' | apt-get -y -o DPkg::options::="--force-confdef" -o DPkg::options::="--force-confold" dselect-upgrade
yes '' | apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o DPkg::options::="--force-confold" -f install

if ! dpkg -l | grep -q phpldapadmin; then
    wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/phpldapadmin/phpldapadmin_1.2.2-6.1~bpo9+1_all.deb -O  phpldapadmin_1.2.2-6.1~bpo9+1_all.deb
    yes '' | dpkg --force-confold --force-confdef -i phpldapadmin_1.2.2-6.1~bpo9+1_all.deb
fi
```

Thanks me ^^